# Assigning user a virtual machine

Tags: windows, vmware-vsphere, vdi, vmware-horizon-view

Is this possible?  I started a new position, and in one of the environments, logging in through horizon view, a user randomly logs on to one of four machines when they login.  Many of the users get frustrated because all of their data and documents are on a different machine than they logged into.

What is the best solution to this problem?

My goal is that when a user logs on, their desktop, documents and everything goes with them.

The only option in Horizon View is which one of the two domains I can log onto, not which machine.

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is that when a user logs on, their desktop, documents everything goes with them.

Yes, this functionality is contained in [folder redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx) and [roaming profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx), and using the two is the standard solution to this problem on a Windows domain.